# HTML tags from Database and display in browser - Play Framework

Tags: html, database, playframework, formatting

I'm using Play framework to render my UI for the browser. I have a String field that I want to display in the browser and the value for this String comes from the database. This String field however contains text with HTML formatting as below:

```
This exam contains questions about core Java initialization, declaration, contro, structures. Questions will be displayed as below:<br><br>public static void main(String args[ ]){<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;int x = 10;<br>}
```

When I render this in the browser, it does not show properly formatted. Here is what the HTML rendering looks like!

[image: HTML Browser Rendering]

Here is how the HTML looks like in the browser!

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on Scala templates:

> **Escaping**
>
> By default, dynamic content parts are escaped according to
>   the template type’s (e.g. HTML or XML) rules. If you want to output a
>   raw content fragment, wrap it in the template content type.
>
> For example to output raw HTML:

```
<p>
  @Html(article.content)
</p>
```